# How to style a dynamically populated string - an interpolated string, in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, frameworks

I am using Angular - **THE JS ANGULAR FRAMEWORK** - and my code is something like this -

```
<p> Server ID: {{ serverID }} server status: {{ serverStatus }}</p>
```

which outputs something like this - **Server ID: 15 server status: offline**

What is the best way to style ONLY the interpolated strings 
either {{ serverID }} or {{ serverStatus }} - only selecting them,
without affecting the rest of the paragraph?

I tried wrapping the interpolated string with some HTML tags -

```
<p> Server ID: <span>{{ serverID }}</span> server status: <div>{{ serverStatus }}</div></p>
```

where of course this HTML element could be anything 
 - `<div>`, `<span>` another `<p>` 
 I just used div and span as an example,
I could also add a class if I wanted to...
and this works.

Now even if I use [ngStyle] or [ngClass] - I will still have to use some HTML element,
there doesn't seem to be a way around it... which is fine.

But I would like to know if there are alternative ways to select the 
 interpolated string in **Agular** - what is best / common practice & most effective ?

To be abundantly clear - I am asking how to select the interpolated tags - **not how to write css** 
 so no need for css code samples, and maybe please don't just repeat the exact same example
 that I already listed, and pretend is a completely new solution that you just came up with 
 - you can just say the 'span method', or wrapping in a HTML tag seems to be the best way, something like this...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution - listed in the details - the span method or any html tag, seems to be the best one

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<p>Server ID: <span>{{ serverID }}</span> server status: <span>{{ serverStatus }}</span></p>
```

css

```
p {
    span {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Try this, of course you can add a class to `span` if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

p's and span's.

In your example, you have the incorrect html. You don't have a starting span. Something like this should suffice

```css
p { color: red; }
p span { color: blue; }
```

```html
<p> 
  Server ID: <span>1234</span> 
  server status: <span>Open</span>
</p>
```